# How to alter data set up to be alterable by drupal_alter()?

Tags: 7

The [**User Import**](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_import) project has an array named `$supported`. It also provides the following hook to alter this array:

```
// hook to add functions to this array.
// Will call all modules implementing hook_field_user_import_supported_alter
drupal_alter('field_user_import_supported', $supported);
```

Implementing this hook in an altogether different project, e.g.

```
function mymodule_field_user_import_supported_alter(&$supported) {
  $supported['mymodule'] = array(
    'save' => 'mymodule_user_import_callback',
  );
}
```

works as one expects.

The **User Import** project allows users to add support for new fields by implementing the required code in a `*.inc`-plugin and placing it in a subdirecory named `supported`.

Rather than adding this to a contributed project I do not own (there is very little chance that my patch will ever be accepted), I want to make use the plugin feature provided by **User Import**.

I've created file a file named `fieldname.inc` and inside `fieldname.inc` , I've implemented `hook_user_import_form_field_match()`. My implementation of this hook follows the same pattern as the generic implementation of the same hook that comes with the project (it is in a file named `field.inc`).  What it does is to add the field with the name "fieldname" to the he pulldown-menu constructed by the project that lets the user assign a field from the imported CSV to a specific field in the Drupal database, and calls to custom custom functions to validate and save fields of type *filename*. This works fine, and  *fieldname* field type is now supported by **User Import** on my site.

However, **User Import** is unaware of this, and when I upload a CSV-file containing fields of type *fieldname* is says:

> Field *fieldname* is not supported

I want to get rid of this bogus warning.

To make this warning go away I need to *alter* the array named `$supported` to add *fieldname* to the list of supported fields.

I *can* do this by hacking the **User Support** project (i.e. changing this array directly). However, this is not a clean solution. Drupal developers are not supposed to hack code they do not own. So I want to have code inside my plugin that alter the array `$supported` belonging to **User Support**.

I've tried to implement `hook_field_user_import_supported_alter` inside `fieldname.inc` file as follows:

```
function fieldname_field_user_import_supported_alter(&$supported) {
  $supported['fieldname'] = array(
    'save' => 'fieldname_user_import_callback',
  );
}
```

This makes the warning disappear, *but* the field is now being added to the pulldown menu twice.  The latter is an undesired side-effect of implementing this hook.

So I want to add this add this element to the end of the array named `$supported`, but *without* having the field being added twice to the pulldown menu.

So the question is: How can make sure that **User Import** knows that *fieldname* is supported without having *fieldname* added twice to the pulldown menu?

Comment: `drupal_alter` is just used to take some data and give it to other modules so they can alter it. It doesn't do anything else (i.e. it doesn't execute the thing that caused you to want to alter the data in the first place). Unless you're _doing_ something with `$supported` after your `drupal_alter` call example, nothing will happen

Comment: To add to what @Clive said, it's not clear what `drupal_alter('mymodule_field_user_import_supported', $supported);` is trying to achieve. The first argument is a hook name (without *hook_*), so that line is invoking the `hook_mymodule_field_user_import_supported()` hook. If no module is implementing that hook, no code is executed.

Comment: @Clive Thanks! That convinced me that I was on the wrong track. I've rewritten the question to get rid of my false assumption and expanded on what I try to do.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I've expanded the question to make it clearer what I try to achieve.